# C# & SQL Server: varbinary convert back into file

Tags: c#, sql-server, file, byte, varbinary

I use the following code:

```
SqlDataReader myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (myReader.Read())
{
   string sqlVarbinary = myReader.GetString(2); // <- varbinary from SQL Server
   string sqlDestPath = myReader.GetString(1); // Path from Sql Server
   string sqlFilename = myReader.GetString(0); // filename from Sql Server
                                
   try
   {
      byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sqlVarbinary); // InvalidCastException, guess here?                                   
      System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes((sqlDestPath + "\\" + sqlFilename), buffer);
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
   }
}

myReader.Close();
```

I want to convert the `varbinary` back to a file and only get invalid cast exceptions. Unfortunately I don't know how to get the varbinary to bytes for the conversion. Does anyone have a different approach?

Comment: **WHY** are you reading the varbinary values into a **string**?? This should be handled as `byte[]` - not a string! `varbinary` is a **binary** format (as its name already gives away) - so you must treat it like that - not convert everything to a string ...... use the **most appropriate** datatype - always, everywhere!

Comment: Oh, thats right, i slept here. byte[] buffer = (byte[])myReader[2]; works fine. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Side point: you need to dispose your reader (and command and connection) with `using`